# Error in Inheritance of class html in osv/fields.py Python/openerp 7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openerp-7

i want to inherit the class html and to redefine the methode _symbol_f(x) which is defined in osv/fields.py in html classe
the definition of this calss is the following:

```
class text(_column):
_type = 'text'

class html(text):
_type = 'html'
_symbol_c = '%s'
def _symbol_f(x):
    if x is None or x == False:
        return None
    return html_sanitize(x)

_symbol_set = (_symbol_c, _symbol_f)
```

i want to redefine the method  _symbol_f(x), so i have created the class wiki_html in the file wiki_html.py like the following

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class wiki_html(fields.html):

_type = 'html'
_symbol_c = '%s'
def _symbol_f(x):
    if x is None or x == False:
        return None
    return html_sanitize_h(x)

_symbol_set = (_symbol_c, _symbol_f)
```

and now i define a field like the following:

```
 'demandes_description':wiki_html('Description demande'),
```

but i have always this error:

```
openerp.osv.orm: <class 'openerp.addons.....wiki_html'> type not supported!
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call the fields with fields.wiki_html.

```
'demandes_description':fields.wiki_html('Description demande'),
```

Comment: sorry, i forget to say that the class  wiki_html is defined in the file wiki_html.py